# How do I customize default error message from spring @Valid validation?

Tags: json, spring

DTO:

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    //..
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    //..
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Default json error:

```
{"timestamp":1417379464584,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException","message":"Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<demo.User> demo.UserController.saveUser(demo.User), with 2 error(s): [Field error in object 'user' on field 'name': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.user.name,NotNull.name,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.name,name]; arguments []; default message [name]]; default message [may not be null]],"path":"/user"}
```

I would like to have my custom json for each error occured. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can perform validation with Errors/BindingResult object.
Add Errors argument to your controller method and customize the error message when errors found.

Below is the sample example, **errors.hasErrors()** returns true when validation is failed.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new ApiErrors(errors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.validation.Errors from spring-context jar

Comment: @user6123723 The ApiError class is a customized class that has the data structure of the message that you want the client to receive, like for example a json with status, code, exception, error and timestamp, that's it.

Comment: Still the approach isn't good enough. I found it more convenient to let an exception to be thrown and manage it in with ExceptionHandling like it's done in JHipster for instance(MethodArgumentNotValidException): https://github.com/jgasmi/jhipster/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/web/rest/errors/ExceptionTranslator.java

Comment: In my case I'll have to use Errors for few methods in my app since I don't want any logging for field validation of Passwords... I can not exclude the LoggingAspect for the handler of MethodArgumentNotValidException since it's defeating its purpose...

Comment: @vesa If you have a object with errors, ```Errors errors``` allows enter to your method for inspecting what errors have there been. **Without this param, an exception will occur before** and you will not able to enter to your method. In other words, with ```Errors errors``` you can analyze your errors programatically from inside your method.

Comment: @BeardOverflow I am trying this but it's working? do I am missing something?

Answer (score 91):

If you want full control over the response message in every controller write a `ControllerAdvice`. For example, that example transform `MethodArgumentNotValidException` into a custom json object:

```
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

/**
 * Kudos http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-adding-validation-to-a-rest-api/
 *
 */
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public Error methodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<org.springframework.validation.FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
    }

    private Error processFieldErrors(List<org.springframework.validation.FieldError> fieldErrors) {
        Error error = new Error(BAD_REQUEST.value(), "validation error");
        for (org.springframework.validation.FieldError fieldError: fieldErrors) {
            error.addFieldError(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return error;
    }

    static class Error {
        private final int status;
        private final String message;
        private List<FieldError> fieldErrors = new ArrayList<>();

        Error(int status, String message) {
            this.status = status;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void addFieldError(String path, String message) {
            FieldError error = new FieldError(path, message);
            fieldErrors.add(error);
        }

        public List<FieldError> getFieldErrors() {
            return fieldErrors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is better since it uses AOP instead of putting validation checks in controller functions

Answer (score 42):

I know this is kind of old question,

But I just run into it and I found some pretty good [article](http://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api) which has also a perfect example in [github](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-rest).

Basically it uses `@ControllerAdvice` as Spring documentation suggests.

So for example catching 400 error will be achieved by overriding one function:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
        //
        final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        for (final ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        final ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), errors);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
    }
}
```

(ApiError class is a simple object to hold status, message, errors)

Answer (score 22):

One way to do it is adding message in @NotNull annotation on entity properties. And adding @Valid annotation in controller request body.

DTO:

```
public class User {
   
    @NotNull(message = "User name cannot be empty")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be empty")
    private String password;

    //..
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
    //..
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
// Add one 
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<List<YourErrorResponse>> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
// Loop through FieldErrors in ex.getBindingResult();
// return *YourErrorReponse* filled using *fieldErrors*
}
```

Comment: Specifying message can be used for other validations as well such as "@"pattern, "@"min, "@"max.  Sorry, I can't say @ + something because stackoverflow thinks I am trying to specify another stackoverflow user.

Answer (score 7):

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ApplicationError validationException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ApplicationError(SysMessageEnum.MSG_005, e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

For customized the error message in JSON format then do the below steps.

**- Create one @Component called CommonErrorHandler**

```
@Component
public class CommonErrorHandler {
public  Map<String,Object> getFieldErrorResponse(BindingResult result){

        Map<String, Object> fielderror = new HashMap<>();
        List<FieldError>errors= result.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors) {
            fielderror.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }return fielderror;
    }

     public ResponseEntity<Object> fieldErrorResponse(String message,Object fieldError){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("isSuccess", false);
        map.put("data", null);
        map.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        map.put("message", message);
        map.put("timeStamp", DateUtils.getSysDate());
        map.put("filedError", fieldError);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(map,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

-- Add InvalidException class

```
public class InvalidDataException extends RuntimeException {

/**
 * @author Ashok Parmar
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4164793146536667139L;

    private BindingResult result;

    public InvalidDataException(BindingResult result) {
        super();
        this.setResult(result);
    }

    public BindingResult getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(BindingResult result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

**- Introduce @ControllerAdvice class**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidDataException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> invalidDataException(InvalidDataException ex, WebRequest request) {

        List<FieldError> errors = ex.getResult().getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors) {
            logger.error("Filed Name ::: " + error.getField() + "Error Message :::" + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return commonErrorHandler.fieldErrorResponse("Error", commonErrorHandler.getFieldErrorResponse(ex.getResult()));
    }
    }
```

-- Use in controller with @Valid and throw exception

```
public AnyBeans update(**@Valid** @RequestBody AnyBeans anyBeans ,
            BindingResult result) {
        AnyBeans resultStr = null;
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            **throw new InvalidDataException(result);**
        } else {
                resultStr = anyBeansService.(anyBeans );
                return resultStr;
        }
    }
```

**-- Output will be in JSON format**

```
{
  "timeStamp": 1590500231932,
  "data": null,
  "message": "Error",
  "isSuccess": false,
  "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
  "filedError": {
    "name": "Name is mandatory"
  }
}
```

Hope this will be work. :-D

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
      protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleGlobalExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
          WebRequest request) {
        log.catching(ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createErrorResp(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
            ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream().map(err -> err.getDefaultMessage())
                .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(", "))),
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

        @Override
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
                MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

           // ex.getBindingResult(): extract the bind result for default message. 
              String errorResult = ex.getBindingResult().toString();
             CustomizedExceptionHandlerResponse exceptionResponse = new CustomizedExceptionHandlerResponse(
                    errorResult, new Date(), request.getDescription(false));

            return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }


}

class CustomizedExceptionHandlerResponse {

   private String message;
   private String status;
   private Date timestamp;

   // constuctor, setters, getters...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some information too.
If you use just `@Valid`, you need to catch `BindException`. If you use `@Valid @RequestBody` catch `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

Some sources:
`HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.getArgumentResolver(MethodParameter parameter):129` - *search which HandlerMethodArgumentResolver support such parameter*
`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter)` - *return true if parameter has annotation* `@RequestBody`

`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:139` - *throw MethodArgumentNotValidException*
`ModelAttributeMethodProcessor:164` - *throw BindException*

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to iterate through errors and build a custom error message :

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDto> handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

        ErrorDto dto = new ErrorDto(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Validation error");

        dto.setDetailedMessages(ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(err -> err.unwrap(ConstraintViolation.class))
            .map(err -> String.format("'%s' %s", err.getPropertyPath(), err.getMessage()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(dto);

    }

    @Data
    public static class ErrorDto {

        private final int status;
        private final String error;
        private final String message;
        private List<String> detailedMessages;

        public ErrorDto(HttpStatus httpStatus, String message) {
            status = httpStatus.value();
            error = httpStatus.getReasonPhrase();
            this.message = message;
        }

    }

}
```

This will give you a response like this in case of error :

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Validation error",
  "detailedMessages": [
    "'yourField' should not be empty."
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but i stumbled across and decided to show a cleaner way of doing what Ksokol showed.

StandardError class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class StandardError {

    private Instant timestamp;
    private Integer status;
    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String path;
}
```

ControllerExceptionHandler class:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<StandardError> notValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String error = "Dados inválidos.";
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY;
        StandardError err = new StandardError(
                Instant.now(),
                status.value(),
                error,
                e.getBindingResult()
                        .getFieldErrors()
                        .stream()
                        .map(FieldError::getDefaultMessage)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                        .toString()
                        .replaceAll("\\[*]*", ""),
                request.getRequestURI()
        );
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(err);
    }
```

This way if you have a custom message on your bean validator, it will appear formatted in a error.

Result:

[image: Result of code above]