# Spring Boot Validation with ControllerAdvice Not Behaving Deterministically

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I have the following setup

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({UserInputValidationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<UserInputValidationResponseBody> handleBadInputException(UserInputValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new UserInputValidationResponseBody().setFieldErrors(ex.getFieldErrors()),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        );
    }

}
```

This is roughly the `@RestController` that throws well formatted validation exceptions

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class MyController {


/**
per the answer, BindingResult must immediately follow the @RequestBody or the item being found
*/
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> foo(@Valid @RequestBody FormPOJO formBody, Principal principal, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // if bindingResult has errors, throw a UserInputValidationException
    }
}
```

And POJOs that I want to bind have JSR-303 validation annotations on them, Spring correctly validate them at Bind time during request parameter binding

However ... while I got this setup to work for a while - then Spring randomly started to bypass the `@RestController` and `@ControllerAdvice`

It appears that now I am receiving `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` ... i.e. the request is getting short circuited

I am running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ...

**EDIT** following suggestion from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663801/how-do-i-customize-default-error-message-from-spring-valid-validation), I added

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

to the controller advice ... it only served to make matters worse. now there is absolutely no validation errors - the client only receives a blank message (which was the symptom of the problem for a while before the current issue surfaced without any code changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out

```
An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.remo.api.portfolios.PortfolioController.put(java.security.Principal,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,com.remo.api.portfolios.Portfolio
```

**tl;dr** Please go ahead and make sure `@RequestBody` is declared ***IMMEDIATELY***  before **BindingResult**