# Customizing / patching 400 response in REST API

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I've built a rest api using Spring & Swagger. Persistence is through Hibernate. The rest api exposes the data in a different format then it is in the DB, so I'm using the dto pattern. Customer vs. CustomerDto. All is good. I've masked the CustomerDto in Swagger with @ApiModel(value="Customer"). All that is good too.

Here's the problem. I'm using validation annotations like @Size, @NotNull, etc. So I get the nice 400 response json:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-11-15T22:25:37.943+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotNull.customerDto.firstName",
```

Seems like MethodArgumentNotValidException doesn't know about the @ApiModel annotation, so it reveals the object name as customerDto.

Is there any way I can patch the response or anything like that? I know I can catch the 400 exception and build my own response, but I'd rather not re-invent the entire wheel to reproduce that entire json.

My company works with financial institutions, so we're not supposed to reveal app internals for security purposes.

EDIT: Should make it clear that I don't want to REPLACE the stock json, I just want to change the customerDto to customer. There are elements in the json besides the message like the codes and stuff. Trying to get to those too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I customize default error message from spring @Valid validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663801/how-do-i-customize-default-error-message-from-spring-valid-validation)

Comment: @Matthias seems like all those suggestions are substituting in different json, so it loses all the codes and arguments and stuff. Trying to avoid recreating all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that error message by default is built in `DefaultErrorAttributes` , so you can extend it to modify the error attributes map.

Here is an example:

```
 import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.DefaultErrorAttributes;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;



     @Component
        public class ExtendedDefaultErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {
          @Override
          public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest webRequest, boolean includeStackTrace) {
            final Map<String, Object> errorAttributes =
                super.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace);

            // MethodArgumentNotValidException includes errors key
            Object errors = errorAttributes.get("errors");
             // .. now you can do whatever you want here... something like completely remove it.  
            if (errors != null) {
              errorAttributes.remove("errors");
            }


   // In here for what you are looking for , you should be doing something like //below, just as an example, but do it properly, I just typed it without checking:

     List<ObjectError> errors = (List<ObjectError>) errorAttributes.get("errors");

        errors.get(0).getCodes()[0].replaceAll("customerDto", "customer");

            return errorAttributes;
          }
        }
```

Or use @ExceptionHandler in ControllerAdvice or Controller class to modify it per how you want.

Example:

```
@ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
  public void handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException manve, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    exceptionLog.error(manve.getMessage());
    Map<String, String> errors =
        manve
            .getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(FieldError::getField, FieldError::getDefaultMessage));
    String errorMessage = "...."
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      errorMessage = mapper.writeValueAsString(errors);
    }

    response.sendError(400, errorMessage);
  }
```

Comment: I was able to touch the response in a response interceptor just before quitting time hit :), but extending DefaultErrorAttributes looks like the better, less obtrusive solution. Thanks!