# return empty body with @Validated annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have this piece of code

```
@PostMapping("/user")
public Response healthcheck(@Validated @RequestBody User user) {
```

and the User is

```
User {

@NotNull 
String name;

@NotNull
String Job;
```

The problem is that I want to return an empty body in case of error with 400 but that returns

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-05-26T17:32:03.536+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "errors": .....
```

How can I make it return an empty body?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664636/2478398) solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! 
weird I didn't see it...

Answer (score 0):

as [@BeUndead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478398/beundead) mentioned -
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663801/how-do-i-customize-default-error-message-from-spring-valid-validation/33664636#33664636) is the answer.