# Spring Boot validation error message not shown in response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-validator

I have following simple project to test spring boot validation. I am using Spring boot version 2.5.6

Validation dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

DTO object

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class DepartmentDTO {

    @NotNull(message = "Department name can not be empty")
    private String name;

    // getter and setter
}
```

REST Controller

```
@RestController
public class DepartmentResource {

    @PostMapping("/departments")
    public ResponseEntity<DepartmentDTO> createDepartment(@Valid @RequestBody DepartmentDTO department) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(department, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I fire a request with **null name** I get the error response, but the message is missing:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-03T09:13:52.729+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/departments"
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this could help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33664636/4752210

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring Boot limits the information included in the error response to reduce the risk of leaking sensitive information about the application to a client. You can explicitly enable additional information in the response by setting [some properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.server.server.error.include-binding-errors) in `application.properties` or `application.yml`.

```
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
server.error.include-message=always
```

Comment: Where would I put them if I put them in my application.yaml file? (And are you talking about the .yaml file used by swagger or open-api to generate the java APIs?)

Comment: I'm referring to the `application.properties` or `application.yml` file loaded by Spring Boot and used to configure the application. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.

Comment: for application.yml file it can be added as shown below:

server:
  port: 8080
  error:
    include-binding-errors: always
    include-message: always

Comment: server.error.include-message=always is  not needed to display the validation message

Comment: If we turn on server.error.include-binding-errors=always, it shows the custom message, but it also reveals sensitive information.  I wonder, if possible to return the custom message without the other sensitive info

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `application.yml`

```
 server:
      error:
        include-stacktrace: never
        include-message: always
        include-binding-errors: always
```