# Spring boot @Valid is not returning proper message

Tags: spring-boot, validation

### Controller Method

```java
    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public Hello hello(@Valid @RequestBody  Hello hello) {
        return hello;
    }
```

### POJO

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;


class Hello{
    @NotBlank(message = "msg must be present")
    String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    
}
```

Upon hitting the above URL with the following payload

```json
{
    "msg":""
}
```

I am getting the following response.

```json
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Invalid request content.",
    "instance": "/hello"
}
```

It should ideally specify the message **msg must be present**.

What's wrong here?

[image]

### The following things have been already tried

- added `server.error.include-message: always` in application.properties file

```java
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("ConstraintViolationException",
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

#### Edit

I had a `@RestControllerAdvice` and it starts working fine, once i remove it. `@RestControllerAdvice` is needed in my case for the customization of exceptions.

Comment: I'm getting 200 with `"msg": ""`

Comment: Strange, it shouldn’t happen

Comment: ah ok, I didn't have `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency, now I'm getting message `"Validation failed for object='hello'. Error count: 1"`

Comment: Actually, i just checked i had a `@RestControllerAdvice`. Once i removed it, it started working fine. But i do need `@RestControllerAdvice` for many other customizations. Updating the same in the question.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663801/how-do-i-customize-default-error-message-from-spring-valid-validation
Seems like your controller advice is the way to go

Comment: Yes, just tried but can't get this worked. Getting `The method handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException) of type RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler must override or implement a supertype method` since the method is declared final in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251573/discussion-between-banan314-and-rahul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a controller advice and return the interpolated message from the exception caught in handler for invalid method argument.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage();
        return new ResponseEntity(bodyOfResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

And after that you should get back message `msg must be present` along with 400. In case you have more constraints, you should iterate over field errors, and `get(0)` is only for demonstration purpose.